# How to read in pandas column as column of lists?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Probably a simple solution but I couldn't find a fix scrolling through previous questions so thought I would ask.

I'm reading in a csv using `pd.read_csv()` One column is giving me issues:

```
0    ['Bupa', 'O2', 'EE', 'Thomas Cook', 'YO! Sushi...
1                                ['Marriott', 'Evans']
2                  ['Toni & Guy', 'Holland & Barrett']
3                                                   []
4                         ['Royal Mail', 'Royal Mail']
```

It looks fine here but when I reference the first value in the column i get:

```
df['brand_list'][0]


Out : '[\'Bupa\', \'O2\', \'EE\', \'Thomas Cook\', \'YO! Sushi\', \'Costa\', \'Starbucks\', \'Apple Store\', \'HMV\', \'Marks & Spencer\', "Sainsbury\'s", \'Superdrug\', \'HSBC UK\', \'Boots\', \'3 Store\', \'Vodafone\', \'Marks & Spencer\', \'Clarks\', \'Carphone Warehouse\', \'Lloyds Bank\', \'Pret A Manger\', \'Sports Direct\', \'Currys PC World\', \'Warrens Bakery\', \'Primark\', "McDonald\'s", \'HSBC UK\', \'Aldi\', \'Premier Inn\', \'Starbucks\', \'Pizza Hut\', \'Ladbrokes\', \'Metro Bank\', \'Cotswold Outdoor\', \'Pret A Manger\', \'Wetherspoon\', \'Halfords\', \'John Lewis\', \'Waitrose\', \'Jessops\', \'Costa\', \'Lush\', \'Holland & Barrett\']'
```

Which is obviously a string not a list as expected. **How can I retain the list type when I read in this data?**

I've tried the `import ast` method I've seen in other posts: `df['brand_list_new'] = df['brand_list'].apply(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x))` Which didn't work.

I've also tried to replicate with dummy dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a' : [['test','test1','test3'], ['test59'], ['test'], ['rhg','wreg']],
                    'b' : [['erg','retbn','ert','eb'], ['g','eg','egr'], ['erg'], 'eg']})

df1['a'][0]


Out: ['test', 'test1', 'test3']
```

Which works as I would expect - this suggests to me that the solution lies in how I am importing the data

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, I was being stupid. The following should work:

```
import ast

df['brand_list_new'] = df['brand_list'].apply(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x))

df['brand_list_new'][0]

Out: ['Bupa','O2','EE','Thomas Cook','YO! Sushi',...]
```

As desired

Comment: `apply(ast.literal_eval)` is enough.

Comment: Indeed it is, if you want a 'free' accepted answer feel free to post and i'll accept your answer

Comment: It doesn't help much, you can accept your own answer two days later.